# Variable of a different Variable

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x

I dont know how to put this so I'm going straight to an example

```
month1=31
month2=28
month3=31
month4=30
#number of days in certain months

monthnumber=3
# I want to find the number of days in the third month

monthnumberstr=str(monthnumber)
daysinmonth=("month"+monthnumberstr)

print(daysinmonth)
```

Now I was expecting it to print *31* but I am getting *month3* as the output.  How do I make it so the output is the variable of the variable. Again I dont know how to say this.  I just want the output to be *31*, not *month3*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asad's Answer is good

OR

in your case, you can try this - :

```
monthnumberstr=str(monthnumber)
daysinmonth= eval("month"+monthnumberstr)
```

You will get value of month3 in daysinmonth ..

:)

Comment: This will work, but is highly inadvisable - `eval` tends to cause more problems than it solves when code gets more complex.

Comment: Thank you.  That was the answer I was looking for but I am going to use a dictionary since it will be simpler.

Comment: @11chubby11 If you decide to use this approach, I would still avoid using `eval`. Take a look at Michal's answer, which does the same thing but avoids dynamically evaluating code.

Answer (score 7):

What you want is an *collection* of the number of days in each month, specifically a list or a dict. Here is an example of how you would do this with a list:

```
days_in_months = [31, 28, ..., 30]
month = 3

print(days_in_months[month]) # prints 30
```

Note that the **first** item in the list is indexed as `days_in_month[0]`, since most collections in Python (and many other programming languages) are zero indexed. Retrieving `days_in_months[3]` will return the **fourth** item in the list.

Per DSM's suggestion, here is an example of how you would use `dict` (which is a bit more complicated, but makes more sense for your use case):

```
days_in_months = {1:31, 2:28, 3:31, 4:30}
month = 3

print(days_in_months[month]) # prints 31
```

In this case, the values are indexed according to keys you explicitly provide, and not according to a zero indexed increasing sequence as in the previous example. The comma separated items in the `{}` literal are *key-value pairs*, mapping each key (the month number) to a value (the number of days in the month). Therefore, accessing `days_in_months[3]` returns 31, and not 30.

Comment: I think the OP might be surprised by Python's zero-indexing, though -- `days_in_months[1] == 28`.  Maybe give the dict equivalent too?

Comment: Also worth noting here I think is [`calendar.monthrange`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) although I suspect the OP might be doing this as homework.

Comment: I think I'll put an extra entry at the start of the collection so it uses up entry 0 and it starts at 1.

Comment: Not homework, just seeing if I can make a program that works out how many days from 1/1/2000 you were born(forward or backwards), then works out which day of the week it would have been(I know it was saturday on 1/1/2000) And no, I haven't forgotten about leap years.  Doing this on my Raspberry Pi and want to see what the speed for something like this will be like.

Comment: @11chubby11 I can't force your hand either way, but you should really use a dictionary, since you are not dealing with a flat list where the index is irrelevant and only order matters. Instead, you are creating a mapping between meaningful entities (month number and number of days in month). The correct thing to do is to use a dict. I probably shouldn't have put in the first example, but I thought it was simpler for someone unfamiliar with collections to grasp.

Comment: A less error prone way to create a dict is `dict(enumerate([31, 28, 31, 30,...], 1)`

Answer (score 3):

Just to be clear, you *can* access a variable indirectly in Python. But this is nowhere near the correct solution for what you're trying to do, and you should just use a proper data structure instead like @Asad suggested.

If someone is really curious on how to access a variable indirectly, you could do:

```
print(locals()[daysinmonth])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are assigning monthnumberstr the string representation of the value of monthnumber, which is "3." So, when you print monthnumberstr, you will print "3." You would want to use a list, like this:

```
months = [31, 28, 31, 30]
monthnumber = 3
print(months[monthnumber])
```